# how to group a json from a sql result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a JSON that's returned from my rails API like this
`[{"tipo":"1","dia":"02/10/2012","empresa_id":"17","horas":"0:15","tempo":"900"},
{"tipo":"2","dia":"02/10/2012","empresa_id":"17","horas":"0:12","tempo":"720"}]`

but I need it to be something like this

`` `[empresa_id: 17, [{"tipo":"1","dia":"02/10/2012","horas":"0:15","tempo":"900"},
{"tipo":"2","dia":"02/10/2012","horas":"0:12","tempo":"720"}]] ``

I need to group the results within `empresa_id`...how do I do that?

Comment: weird expected final result. look here for first track: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by

Comment: Can you change the method that supplies the data or are you stuck with it and having to remap the array you posted on the fly? And when you say "JSON" does that mean you have to remap it in your Javascript or in Ruby before it gets sent back to the browser?

Comment: I done this: `<%= @result.group_by{|i| i['empresa_id']}.to_json %>` which results in this: `{"17":[{"tipo":"1","dia":"02/10/2012","empresa_id":"17","horas":"0:15","tempo":"900"},{"tipo":"2","dia":"02/10/2012","empresa_id":"17","horas":"0:12","tempo":"720"}]}` group_by did the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
require 'json'

s = '[{"tipo":"1","dia":"02/10/2012","empresa_id":"17","horas":"0:15","tempo":"900"}, {"tipo":"2","dia":"02/10/2012","empresa_id":"17","horas":"0:12","tempo":"720"}]'
j = JSON.parse(s)
r = j.inject({}) do |f,c|
    key = c.delete('empresa_id')
    (f[key]||=[]) << c
    f
end
p r
```

resulting in

```
{"17"=>[{"tipo"=>"1", "dia"=>"02/10/2012", "horas"=>"0:15", "tempo"=>"900"}, {"tipo"=>"2", "dia"=>"02/10/2012", "horas"=>"0:12", "tempo"=>"720"}]}
```

### See [live demo here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?lang=ruby&file=how-to-group-a-json-from-a-sql-result.rb&run=true)

Answer (score 3):

In your model's view folder, create a file called modelname.json.erb. Here, you can use ruby code to edit how you want to format your json. Here's an untested code example of what it might look like:

```
[
<% i = 0
@modelname.each do |model| %>
    {
        "id": <%= model.id %>,
        "name": "<%= model.name %>"
    }<% if i != (@modelname.size - 1) %>,<% end %>
    <% i += 1 %>
<% end %>
]
```

In your controller, by default you will have something like this for the output:

```
format.json { render json: @modelname }
```

Change it to this:

```
format.json
```

By doing this, it will look for the json view you just created!